# Reading cell with formula gives different result from excel file - Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I'm writing a program that:

- Opens an excel file
- Writes a formula to a cell - SUM(item:item);
- Reads the value of the output of the formula

Given my the snippet below, I could successfully write down the formula and checking the excel file would yield the correct answer of SUM.

```
            Row row = sheet.getRow(2); //which is row 3 at excel file
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0); //so that's cell A3
            cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:A2)");
```

Sadly when I read the value of the formula, which is supposed to be "101.0" it gives me a "0.0".

```
            row = sheet.getRow(2);
            Cell currentCell = row.getCell(0); //getting value of formula which we wrote above
            if (currentCell != null) {
                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    if (currentCell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.println("VALUE FROM PROGRAM: "+currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried something out which was to write a formula via the MS Excel app to compare the value it returns when read by the program.
Turns out, for my progam-written formula, it's the same incorrect value but for the one written using MS Excel, the value was perfectly read.

**What am I missing here? Why won't the answer of the first formula be read correctly? Hoping someone can help. Thanks in advance.**

Here's what's inside my file:

```
        |    A      |     B     |
    1   |    1      |     2     |
    2   |   100     |    100    |
    3   |=SUM(A1:A2)|=SUM(B1:B2)| //where A3 was written by java and B3 was written using MS Excel
```

Here's the full code inside main:

```
    String surveyDirectory = "DATABASE.xlsx";
    XSSFWorkbook workbookx;
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    FileInputStream fis;

    File file = new File(surveyDirectory);

    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(surveyDirectory);
            workbookx = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            Sheet sheet = workbookx.getSheetAt(0);

            //writing a formula to file

            Row row = sheet.createRow(2); //which is row 3 at excel file
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0); //so that's A3 in excel
            cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:A2)");

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(surveyDirectory); //write it down the file
            workbookx.write(outputStream);
            outputStream.close();

            System.out.println("DONE WRITING");

            //reading the fomula file
            //we are accessing same sheet
            row = sheet.getRow(2);
            Cell currentCell = row.getCell(0); //getting value of formula which we wrote above
            System.out.println("FORMULA at A3: " + currentCell);
            if (currentCell != null) {
                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    if (currentCell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.println("VALUE FROM PROGRAM: "+currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            row = sheet.getRow(2); //formula is =SUM(B1:B2)
            currentCell = row.getCell(1); //getting value of formula which was written vie MS Excel
            System.out.println("FORMULA at B3: " + currentCell);
            if (currentCell != null) {
                if (currentCell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    if (currentCell.getCachedFormulaResultType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.println("VALUE FROM MS EXCEL: "+currentCell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("DONE READING");
            fis.close();
            workbookx.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TextHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Here's the output I get:

```
    DONE WRITING
    FORMULA at A3: SUM(A1:A2)
    VALUE FROM PROGRAM: 0.0
    FORMULA at B3: SUM(B1:B2)
    VALUE FROM MS EXCEL: 102.0
    DONE READING
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**EDIT**: I'm using Apache POI 3.17

**EDIT #2**: Here's the working snippet.

```
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2); 
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0); 
    cell.setCellFormula("SUM(A1:A2)");
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbookx.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the formula doesn't update the associated value in the cell. You need to evaluate the cell too, [as described here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html).
You can use `FormulaEvaluator.evaluate()` to "peek" at the result, or `FormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell()` to save the result into the cell like Excel does.

Comment: WOW. I got the output I wanted. Just a follow up though. Did I do it right by just placing evaulateFormulaCell(currentCell) after setting the formula? Just making sure it won't cause further errors. I added the working snippet above (See EDIT 2)